# Какие сообщения принимает окно приложения Windows, когда пользователь перемещает мышь с нажатой левой клавишей?

Tags: события, visual-c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие сообщения принимает окно приложения Windows, когда пользователь нажал левую клавишу мыши и перемещает мышь с нажатой левой клавишей? И какое сообщение получит окно, когда пользователь отпустил левую клавишу мыши? Как вообще в приложении Visual C++ определить ситуацию, что пользователь перемещает мышь, удерживая её левую клавишу в нажатом состоянии?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря где происходит событие.

Если внутри окна — то `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`.

Если в non-client area, то `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`, `WM_MOVING`/`WM_MOVE` (в зависимости от системы), `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` и `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`.

---

Если вам нужен drag'n'drop, тут есть различные случаи. Если вы таскаете свои собственные контролы в одном окне, то можно обойтись «малой кровью». Делается примерно так:

1. На `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, если вы ещё не в режиме перетаскивания, и находитесь в нужном месте, переходите в режим перетаскивания. (Может быть, достаточно булевого флага.) Не забудьте mouse capture, чтобы event'ы приходили даже если мышь уйдёт за окно.
2. На `WM_LBUTTONUP`, если вы были в режиме перетаскивания, отпускайте capture и выполняйте Drop.
3. На `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, если вы в режиме перетаскивания, выставьте соответствующий курсор, и отрисуйте контрол в новом месте, если в это место можно перетаскивать. Если перетаскивать нельзя, выставьте запрещающий курсор. Также можете подсветить drop target, например. Если надо (например, курсор упирается в стенку), отскроллируйте view.
4. У вас может потеряться mouse capture (например, пользователь может переключиться в другое приложение), это надо корректно обрабатывать. На `WM_CAPTURECHANGED`, если вы в режиме перетаскивания, корректно закройте этот режим.

([Вот](http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/productions/articles/dragdroptab.htm) подробнее на английском и с MFC.)

В случае, если вам нужно таскать, например, файлы, или что-нибудь из другого приложения, придётся включать тяжёлую артиллерию в виде OLE. Вот [статья](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840/How-to-Implement-Drag-and-Drop-Between-Your-Progra) с достаточно подробным описанием. А также [каноническое описание](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96826a87.aspx) от Microsoft.

Comment: Если я определю какие-то действия для обработчика WM_MOUSEMOVE, то они будут выполняться безотносительно того - нажата левая клавиша мыши или нет?

Comment: @user3769902: Вам придётся на `WM_MOUSEDOWN` запоминать, что началась операция. А вы хотите реализовать drag-and-drop? Если да, надо по-другому. Для этого есть специальные средства.

Comment: Какие? Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку. Мне нужно реализовать drag-and-drop окружности (сёркла) и вращение окружности (сёркла). Вращать её я должен мышью при нажатой левой клавише мыши. Ну а drag-and-drop всегда делается при нажатой левой клавише.

Comment: Вся графика у меня делается в Direct2D.

Comment: @user3769902: обновил ответ

Comment: Когда я задаю для объекта геометрии D2D1PathGeometry трансформацию по перемещению, то перемещается тот же самый объект без его пересоздания?

Comment: По идее, да. С другой стороны, там где-то в глубине имплементации WPF может быть какой-то вспомогательный объект и пересоздаётся, но на нас это не должно влиять.

Comment: Я пишу своё приложение не в .NET, а в неуправляемом C++ приложение Win32. Я использую ID2D1PathGeometry, а вот для выполнения translate transform при drag-and-drop геометрии какая разница какую геометрию перемещать: ID2D1PathGeometry или  ID2D1TransformedGeometry? Если в окне несколько геометрий.

Comment: @user3769902: И правда :) Спутал. А такое уже умеет Win32? Не знал.

Comment: Да в Direcr2D можно трансформировать в Win32. Мне важно, а как после того, как DragDetect вернёт true определить над какой именно геометрией находится курсор мыши (у меня в окне несколько ID2D1PathGeometry-геометрий и не все одинаковые). Вот как идентифицировать над какой из них мышь?

Comment: @user3769902: Судя по всему, вам пригодится [`FillContainsPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).